# UWP unit test compile errors

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I'm migrating WPF projects to UWP. While setting up new unit test projects in UWP I'm running into errors when the new unit test targets a migrated project that in turn has a dependency on another project in the solution. (Each solution builds w/o errors)

```
Solution Explorer:
Communication.Base(.csproj uwp class library)
Communication(.csProj uwp class library) -> depends on Communication.Base
Unit_Test(.csproj)
```

If Unit_Test project references both Communication.Base and Communication, I get several errors when attempting to run an empty test method:

```
Duplicate Entry. error PRI175       

Error       0xdef00532 - Conflicting values for resource 'System.Design/ClassComments1' Unit_Test C:\v7\Development\Unit_Test\GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE
```

When I search the file contents for ClassComments1 I find these:

```
  .\obj\x86\Debug\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0\en-US\System.Design.resw (1 hit)
    Line 132:   <data name="ClassComments1" xml:space="preserve">
  .\obj\x86\Debug\System.Design\en-US\System.Design.resw (1 hit)
    Line 3821:   <data name="ClassComments1" xml:space="preserve">
```

Not sure how to fix these though. Has anyone run into this issue?

**Update**

After finishing the migration of all projects, I find that this error effects my ability to compile and run the entire application. I've rebuilt all of the projects files (each of them compile and produce it's dll) but the main application wont compile now:

13>error PRI175 : 0x80073b0f - Processing Resources failed with error : Duplicate Entry.
13>GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : error PRI277: 0xdef00532 - Conflicting values for resource 'System.Design/ClassComments1'

**Update**

I tried downgrading all of the project in this solution to pre-win 10 creators update in 2017 then opened the solution in 2015. Unfortunately, the Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform references are broken on opening the solution and 2015 nuget can't successfully restore them even when selecting the package to install. Tons of nuget errors before it fails.

Comment: I dont think you can migrate WPF unit test to UWP .

Comment: This error is produced by the unit test project compile. The migrated code is in the communications projects. There is only one empty test method in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix this build error by singling out the problem project by including each project in a unit test (that failed each time with the same error.) As I added and removed projects from the test, I noticed that the one that seemed to cause the issue had the following reference:

```
Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0
```

The reference was added by Visual Studio automatically during the assist process when I was updating the code base to compile against UWP. Once I remove this reference the whole solution compiles w/o error.