# Xamarin.Forms.UWP - error PRI175

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I've got 3 Projects inside my Solution.

- Project A (Xamarin.Windows.UWP - This is the exectuable Project) (References Project B + C)
- Project B (Xamarin.Forms - This is a class Library)
- Project C (Xamarin.Forms.UWP - Acts as a Renderer Library) ( References Project B)

The Problem here is, that if Project A references both B + C, I get 2 errors when building:

- Error PRI175 - duplicate Entry
- GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE - 0xdef00532 - Conflicting values for resource "

Unfortunatly this is everything I get.
Removing reference Project C or B from Project A lets me build without any problems, but I need classes from both Project B + C in Project A.

So, does anyone knows whats causing these Build errors here?

Thanks a lot for your help!

## Edit:

I recreated the structure and the same error appears. The solution can be found [here.](https://github.com/DirtyNative/TestSolution) Open **TestSolutionC**, Build TestSolutionC.UWP

Comment: I could not reproduce this cross reference issue in my side, could you share a simple sample?

Comment: Anyone resolved this? I'm having the same issue here. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d2373a3-f065-4a4e-b400-71a5af93745c/uwp-compile-errors-x86-visual-studio-2017?forum=wpdevelop suggests that this could happen due to duplicate references. But I couldn't find any.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: Unfortunatly I didn't yet. But I uploaded this Testproject to repcuduce that error

Comment: im looking into it still, i think it has to do with UWP not working well in NETcore2.0

Comment: I am thinking this is caused because a UWP referencing a UWP Project, and both are containing some files with the same name

Answer (score 3):

Try this - In your main app project file, under top-most `<PropertyGroup>`, add:

```
<DisableEmbeddedXbf>false</DisableEmbeddedXbf>
```

[Related discussion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/247864/uwp-builderror-at-makepri-0x80073b0f-and-0xdef0053.html) - Developer Community thread

Comment: According to the link, as of August 2018, this (the need to put the <DisableEmbeddedXbf> workaround in your project file) was a bug that was fixed in visual studio.  So it seems this solution is obsolete.

Comment: @Stephen - Actually, the error seems to be cause by the dependencies of  the component libraries being used.  If, for example, you get this error using a third-party control and the third party has not updated their control, this work-around remains valid.  To this day, I must leave this setting in place to be able to compile projects where this third-party library is used.

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to many reasons. Please check the solutions mentioned below.

**SOLUTION 1:**
When you are adding a third party render library (Project C), check that you have the same version of Xamarin.Forms used throughout the solution projects. Conflicts may occur if multiple versions of Xamarin.Forms have been used.

Use the same Xamarin.Forms version or update the entire solution's Xamarin.Forms version to a latest stable version from the NuGet Manager

**SOLUTION 2:**
Make sure that your project files within the solution do not contain unwanted references. If found, resolve duplicate references, Clean and Rebuild the project.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/45217513/4353760

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to build a UWP unit test project, which was referencing a different version of Xamarin.Forms relative to the project I was trying to test. Consolidating the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package via the package manager fixed the issue.